# screenshots in BDD cucumber framework in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, bdd

Currently, I am using below code to take screenshot of particular action(calling in method where screenshot is important) performed. But I need to take screenshot of every page as we use to do while functional testing (before- as page loads and after- values are entered on that page) and it should name screenshot as `@before- PageName` and `@after-PageName`
If anybody know how to take screenshot of whole Page, please let me know.

```
public void getscreenshot(WebDriver driver) throws Exception {

        File scr = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

        File dest = new File(("user.dir")+"screenshot" + timestamp() + ".png");
        FileUtils.copyFile(scr, dest);
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Take a screenshot with Selenium WebDriver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422262/take-a-screenshot-with-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: I have added below code: File scrFile =((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE); FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("C:\\Automation\\target\\zucchini-reports\\testScreenSh‌​ot.jpg")); if (testResult.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) { scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE); FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("C:\\Automation\\target\\zucchini-reports\\testScreenSh‌​ot.jpg")); getting error message takeScreenShotOnFailure(com.Runner.AbstractStepDefinitionTes‌​t) Time elapsed: 74.844 sec <<< FAILURE! –

Answer (score 0):

Check with [QAF](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf). You can achieve it by adding log message with screenshot, for example:

```
Reporter.logWithScreenShot("before change")
//perform your stuff
Reporter.logWithScreenShot("after change")
```

You can take a quick tour by following [Step-By-Step-Tutorial](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-step-by-step-tutorial/wiki)

Answer (score 0):

You could use https://saucelabs.com/ for this (its a paid service, I'm not affiliated with them, nor am I recommending them). They offer videos of your scenarios as well as screenshots.